# Curved lines with tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows, charts, arrow-curve

Consider:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article}

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} % Better typography
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\tikzstyle{error} = [circle, draw, fill=red!20,
text width=4.0em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20,
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes

\node [block] (X1) {X1};
\node [block, below of=X1, node distance=3cm] (X2) {X2};
\node [block, below right = .25cm and 1.5cm of X1] (Y) {Y};
\node [error, right of = X1, node distance=3.7cm] (error) {error};
% Draw edges

\path [line] (X1) -- (X2);
%\path [line] (error) -- node {1}(X1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm looking for a way to draw a curved double headed arrow between X1 and X2 like this:

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Have a look at [Example: Borrowers and lenders](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/borrowers-and-lenders/)

Comment: Also have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209942/curved-arrows-in-tikz?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Curved Arrows in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/209942/curved-arrows-in-tikz)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I made the following:

- Reduce your code example to minimal working example (MWE) by removing all not used libraries and packages.
- Use recent syntax in definitions of used styles (`\tikzstyle` is deprecated).
- For positioning of picture's elements use syntax determined by library `positioning` (observe difference between `...=of ...` and `...=of ...`).
- For arrows between blocks I used option `bend right`:

  ```
  \documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc, positioning}

  \tikzset{
  error/.style = {circle, draw, fill=red, align=center,
                  inner sep=0pt},
  block/.style = {rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, rounded corners,
                  text width=5em, minimum height=4em, align=center},
          }

  \begin{document}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 8mm and 12mm
                          ]
  % Place nodes
  \node [block] (X1) {X1};
  \node [block, below=of X1] (X2) {X2};
  \node [block, below right=of X1] (Y) {Y};
  \node [error, right=of X1] (error) {error};
  % Draw edges
  \draw [Latex-Latex] (X1.west) to[bend right=45] (X2.west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Note: I didn't bother with exactly replicating the position of your nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} % Better typography
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings} 
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\tikzstyle{error} = [circle, draw, fill=red!20, 
text width=4.0em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes

\node [block] (X1) {X1};
\node [block, below of=X1, node distance=3cm] (X2) {X2};
\node [block, below right = .25cm and 1.5cm of X1] (Y) {Y};
\node [error, right of = X1, node distance=3.7cm] (error) {error};
% Draw edges

\path [<->] (X1) edge[bend right=90] (X2);
%\path [line] (error) -- node {1}(X1);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can control the "impact angles" with `in` and `out`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt]{article} 

\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype} % Better typography
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows in-line images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings} 
\usepackage{mathpazo} % Use the Palatino font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\tikzstyle{error} = [circle, draw, fill=red!20, 
text width=4.0em, text badly centered, node distance=3cm, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=blue!20, 
text width=5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']
\tikzstyle{cloud} = [draw, ellipse,fill=red!20, node distance=3cm,
minimum height=2em]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm, auto]
% Place nodes

\node [block] (X1) {X1};
\node [block, below of=X1, node distance=3cm] (X2) {X2};
\node [block, below right = .25cm and 1.5cm of X1] (Y) {Y};
\node [error, right of = X1, node distance=3.7cm] (error) {error};
% Draw edges

\draw [latex-latex,in=135,out=225] (X1.west) to (X2.west);
%\path [line] (error) -- node {1}(X1);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]